# LED RGB how it works

Tags: microcontroller, led, rgb

I am working with an RGB LED. For my project I need just green and red light but I don't want to add two separate diodes cause they need to be at the same place. I don't have so much space on MC so I was thinking of not connecting blue wire. Is that ok? If not I should extend MC?

[image]

Comment: You can leave it disconnected. LEDs with just red and green also exist.

Comment: Traditionally you'd drive the LED cathode from the electronic switching element and fixed wire the anode as low side drivers have historically been more capable, but modern MCUs may try to do almost as well in both directions.  Do consider MCU current ratings, individually and in total.  Also if it's SMD triple check the pinout and orientation before you finalize the board, even get one and carefully touch wires to it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> i was thinking not connecting blue wire. Is that ok?

Yes, that is completely OK. You don't have to connect all of the 3 (or 4, for RGBW) LEDs in a package, if you don't want to use them all.